# Add classes + taxonomy terms to wp_list_pages() output

Tags: css, wp-list-pages

I'm outputting a list of pages in my custom post type — a kind of tree — using `wp_list_pages()`.

All's going well, except now I want to put some classes in the li's for styling. Even that's not going too bad with the help of this guy:

```
function tsep_page_css_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) {
  if ( !isset($args['post_type']) || !is_singular($args['post_type']) )
    return $css_class;

  global $post;
  $current_page  = $post->ID;
  $_current_page = $post;
  _get_post_ancestors($_current_page);

  if ( isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors) )
    $css_class[] = 'current-page-ancestor';
  if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
    $css_class[] = "current-page-item";  
  elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
    $css_class[] = 'current-page-parent';

  return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'tsep_page_css_class', 10, 5 );
```

This basically prints out `current-page-item`, `ancestor` or `parent` in my `<li>`. This part works really well. What I want however, is to print out taxonomy terms from my "content-type" taxonomy in the `<li>` classes too.  So, one might look like this:  `

I've got a start on it:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'content-type' );

        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 

            $content_type = array();

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $content_type[] = $term->name;
            }

            $the_content_type = join( ", ", $the_content_type );

        endif;
```

But in the end, `$the_content_type` doesn't seem to return anything.

How can I get `$the_content_type` to return a value, and how would I put that value in the `$css_class[]` above?

Hope some of this made sense!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't WordPress already at the class `current_page_parent`, `current_page_ancestor` and `current_page_item` (see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1031)). The filter you are using is called on 1046.

As for your question, you create the array `$content_type` and then attempt to make a string out of `$the_content_type`.

Try:

```
 function wpse56088_page_css_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ){
     $terms = get_the_terms( $page->ID, 'content-type' );
     if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        $term_names = wp_list_pluck($terms,'name');

        //Add term names to array of classes
        $css_class = array_merge($css_class, $term_names);
     }
     return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'wpse56088_page_css_class', 10, 5 );
```

Note `$css_class` is suppose to be an array of class names.

Comment: I'll try that now.  I think that filter on 1046 only works for actual pages, not custom pages. *I think*

Comment: Close. It adds the class fine, but does so based on the $post->ID, instead of itself.  IE:  It adds the tax term associated the current post to each <li> in the output.

Comment: Not all of these are Sections: http://cl.ly/2a0l3V1G3A3f3M1H3H0b.   Nor are they all Topics: http://cl.ly/3F0Z3c2H2y1S3P3h0l47

Comment: My bad - `get_the_terms` should reference the passed `$page` variable, not the (undefined) `$post` variable. The latter is returning `null` and so in the absence of an ID, WordPress uses the current page. Editing answer...

Comment: wp_list_pluck!!!!! Of course. Never thought of doing it this way. Huge thanks!